# code have "import com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessor",eclipse give me a warning

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am a new bee of java, today I am reading the source code of vysper which is an open source program of apache, when I imported the maven project into the eclipse, I met a lot of warnings:

when the codes `import com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessor` I will get a warning:

```
Access restriction: The type AnnotationProcessor is not accessible due to restriction on required 
 library /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
```

who can give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse go to

> Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated and Restricted APIs

Set `Forbidden reference (access rules)` to `Ignore`. However, please note that these warnings are there for a reason. It's okay if you simply want to browse but your application code should not be dependent on restricted or deprecated libraries because they are subject to change or removal.

Comment: Confirm. This API has been deprecated in the last release. 
https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/apt_api_files